# ExtJS File upload response?

Tags: java, file-upload, extjs, httpresponse

I'm trying to validate the contents of some files through a web interface and use the response to enable / disable some other functionality ... like a save button. I've got as far as the submit and file handling (stubbed) but I cant seem to get my response to work properly.

Problem : on response tries to make user download a file with the response contents. I want to just pass the response to the success function to be handled.

JS Function Code:

```
function validateCopybook() {
        //submit values. 
        console.log("validating");
        if (this.getForm().isValid()) {
            this.getForm().submit({
            url : 'batch/validateCopybook.json',
            waitMsg : 'Validating...',
            success : function(form, action) {
                this.msg('Success', 'Processed file on the server');


                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Server side code :

```
public ModelAndView validateCopybook(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
    // Check whether we're dealing with a multipart request
    String contentHeader = request.getHeader("content-type");
    boolean isMultipart = (contentHeader != null && contentHeader.indexOf("multipart/form-data") != -1);

    if (isMultipart == false)
    {
        return Helper.errorResponse("not multipart");
    }
    else
    {
        DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest reqM = (DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> fileMap = reqM.getMultiFileMap();
        MultipartFile copyIn = fileMap.get("copy-path-in").get(0);
        MultipartFile copyOut = fileMap.get("copy-path-out").get(0);
    }

    System.out.println(response.getContentType());
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    ModelAndView mav = Helper.successResponse("success");
    return mav;
}
```

Response returned :

```
ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'json'; model is {model={data={"success":true,"info":"success","dataLength":0,"data":[]}}}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you check the exact response with Firebug and let us know what it says. Is the Content-Type set correctly on the response header? What is the exact content of the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I wasnt setting the response header correctly

```
 response.setContentType("application/json");
```

wasnt enough.

```
        MappingJacksonJsonView view = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
    view.setContentType("text/html");
    Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    responseMap.put("success", true);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(view, responseMap);
```

Works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to just pass the response to
>   the success function to be handled.

You already have the response from the server in your success function!. The `action` parameter in the success function holds details of your response. You can access the response through `action.result.variablename`.

Comment: Yes. My point was that the success function wasn't being hit because the response header type wasnt set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Server response type should be "text/html". 
asp.net mvc result:

```
return Json(new
{
    success = true,
    msg = "Your file has been uploaded",
    data = new
        {
            name, size
        }
}, "text/html");
```

Live demo is [here](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-upload-to-asp-net-mvc-demo.html)